# Nesting SVGs with center alignment

Tags: css, svg, vector

I need to place icon SVGs of random shape (i.e. not necessarily square-ish) on top of a pin/marker SVG.

I can easily stack them but I'm not sure how to align them so regardless of the shape, the icons are vertically and horizontally aligned.

[image]

**Marker SVG**:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="45">
      <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="154.5%" height="509.1%" x="-27.3%" y="-204.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(1 1)">
        <ellipse cx="15" cy="37.467" fill="#999" fill-opacity=".9" filter="url(#a)" rx="11" ry="1.467"/>
        <path fill="#006893" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#006893" d="M15 0C6.448 0 0 6.759 0 15.726c0 11.28 13.944 21.44 14.537 21.867.138.1.302.149.463.149a.784.784 0 0 0 .463-.15C16.055 37.167 30 27.007 30 15.727 30 6.76 23.552 0 15 0z"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

**Icon SVG**:

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title>bicycle</title><path d="M5.5,6.137a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H6.909a.249.249,0,0,1,.231.156l.637,1.568a.251.251,0,0,1-.036.25l-.35.437a.25.25,0,0,1-.3.07A4.894,4.894,0,0,0,5,10.137a5,5,0,1,0,4.856,6.19.25.25,0,0,1,.243-.19h.4a1,1,0,0,0,.807-.409l4.281-5.837a.247.247,0,0,1,.236-.1.252.252,0,0,1,.2.161l.281.762a.251.251,0,0,1-.095.293,4.978,4.978,0,1,0,2.79-.87,3.824,3.824,0,0,0-.549.046.25.25,0,0,1-.27-.161L16.92,6.6a.249.249,0,0,1,.174-.329l1.742-.435a1,1,0,0,0-.485-1.941L15.8,4.532a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.042,1.974l.08.217a.253.253,0,0,1-.008.193.25.25,0,0,1-.142.129L9.764,8.8a.251.251,0,0,1-.316-.141l-.113-.279A.178.178,0,0,1,9.5,8.137a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-.5,12a3,3,0,1,1,2.658-4.364.25.25,0,0,1-.222.364H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H7.436a.25.25,0,0,1,.222.364A2.985,2.985,0,0,1,5,18.137Zm5.049-4.076a.1.1,0,0,1-.174-.036,4.941,4.941,0,0,0-.927-1.916.249.249,0,0,1,0-.309l.609-.761a.252.252,0,0,1,.111-.08L12.5,9.95a.25.25,0,0,1,.286.383ZM19,18.137a3,3,0,0,1-3-3,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,.8-2.022.249.249,0,0,1,.417.084l.842,2.284a1,1,0,1,0,1.876-.692l-.964-2.617a.028.028,0,0,1,0-.025A.028.028,0,0,1,19,12.137a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z"/></svg>
```

**Stacked (Incorrect Alignment)**:

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="45">
      <defs>
        <filter id="a" width="154.5%" height="509.1%" x="-27.3%" y="-204.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(1 1)">
        <ellipse cx="15" cy="37.467" fill="#999" fill-opacity=".9" filter="url(#a)" rx="11" ry="1.467"/>
        <path fill="#006893" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#006893" d="M15 0C6.448 0 0 6.759 0 15.726c0 11.28 13.944 21.44 14.537 21.867.138.1.302.149.463.149a.784.784 0 0 0 .463-.15C16.055 37.167 30 27.007 30 15.727 30 6.76 23.552 0 15 0z"/>
        <g fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero">
          <path d="M5.5,6.137a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H6.909a.249.249,0,0,1,.231.156l.637,1.568a.251.251,0,0,1-.036.25l-.35.437a.25.25,0,0,1-.3.07A4.894,4.894,0,0,0,5,10.137a5,5,0,1,0,4.856,6.19.25.25,0,0,1,.243-.19h.4a1,1,0,0,0,.807-.409l4.281-5.837a.247.247,0,0,1,.236-.1.252.252,0,0,1,.2.161l.281.762a.251.251,0,0,1-.095.293,4.978,4.978,0,1,0,2.79-.87,3.824,3.824,0,0,0-.549.046.25.25,0,0,1-.27-.161L16.92,6.6a.249.249,0,0,1,.174-.329l1.742-.435a1,1,0,0,0-.485-1.941L15.8,4.532a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.042,1.974l.08.217a.253.253,0,0,1-.008.193.25.25,0,0,1-.142.129L9.764,8.8a.251.251,0,0,1-.316-.141l-.113-.279A.178.178,0,0,1,9.5,8.137a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-.5,12a3,3,0,1,1,2.658-4.364.25.25,0,0,1-.222.364H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H7.436a.25.25,0,0,1,.222.364A2.985,2.985,0,0,1,5,18.137Zm5.049-4.076a.1.1,0,0,1-.174-.036,4.941,4.941,0,0,0-.927-1.916.249.249,0,0,1,0-.309l.609-.761a.252.252,0,0,1,.111-.08L12.5,9.95a.25.25,0,0,1,.286.383ZM19,18.137a3,3,0,0,1-3-3,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,.8-2.022.249.249,0,0,1,.417.084l.842,2.284a1,1,0,1,0,1.876-.692l-.964-2.617a.028.028,0,0,1,0-.025A.028.028,0,0,1,19,12.137a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very simple.

Just embed your `<svg>` icon into the other SVG.  Set the `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` of the embedded `<svg>` element to the size and position of the square area you want the icon to be positioned within. And SVG will do the rest (including the centering).

In this case, I have chosen a square that is: `x="6" y="6" width="20" height="20"`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="45">
  <defs>
    <filter id="a" width="154.5%" height="509.1%" x="-27.3%" y="-204.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(1 1)">
    <ellipse cx="15" cy="37.467" fill="#999" fill-opacity=".9" filter="url(#a)" rx="11" ry="1.467"/>
    <path fill="#006893" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#006893" d="M15 0C6.448 0 0 6.759 0 15.726c0 11.28 13.944 21.44 14.537 21.867.138.1.302.149.463.149a.784.784 0 0 0 .463-.15C16.055 37.167 30 27.007 30 15.727 30 6.76 23.552 0 15 0z"/>
  </g>

  <svg x="6" y="6" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#fff"><title>bicycle</title><path d="M5.5,6.137a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H6.909a.249.249,0,0,1,.231.156l.637,1.568a.251.251,0,0,1-.036.25l-.35.437a.25.25,0,0,1-.3.07A4.894,4.894,0,0,0,5,10.137a5,5,0,1,0,4.856,6.19.25.25,0,0,1,.243-.19h.4a1,1,0,0,0,.807-.409l4.281-5.837a.247.247,0,0,1,.236-.1.252.252,0,0,1,.2.161l.281.762a.251.251,0,0,1-.095.293,4.978,4.978,0,1,0,2.79-.87,3.824,3.824,0,0,0-.549.046.25.25,0,0,1-.27-.161L16.92,6.6a.249.249,0,0,1,.174-.329l1.742-.435a1,1,0,0,0-.485-1.941L15.8,4.532a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.042,1.974l.08.217a.253.253,0,0,1-.008.193.25.25,0,0,1-.142.129L9.764,8.8a.251.251,0,0,1-.316-.141l-.113-.279A.178.178,0,0,1,9.5,8.137a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-.5,12a3,3,0,1,1,2.658-4.364.25.25,0,0,1-.222.364H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H7.436a.25.25,0,0,1,.222.364A2.985,2.985,0,0,1,5,18.137Zm5.049-4.076a.1.1,0,0,1-.174-.036,4.941,4.941,0,0,0-.927-1.916.249.249,0,0,1,0-.309l.609-.761a.252.252,0,0,1,.111-.08L12.5,9.95a.25.25,0,0,1,.286.383ZM19,18.137a3,3,0,0,1-3-3,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,.8-2.022.249.249,0,0,1,.417.084l.842,2.284a1,1,0,1,0,1.876-.692l-.964-2.617a.028.028,0,0,1,0-.025A.028.028,0,0,1,19,12.137a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z"/></svg>

</svg>
```

Comment: No doubt is it very simple (for the author of AndroidSVG!) :D Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

Answer  @Paul LeBeau is good for its originality, but unfortunately with this solution, the combined icon can only be used once.
Because different parts of the icons are located in different instances of `svg`

Suppose you need to use combined  icons multiple times as map pointers.
Then you have to use another solution for positioning the components of the icon relative to each other.

This can be done using the command `transform ="translate (2.5 2)"`

Add raster map to svg

`<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylp6r.png" width="100%" height="100%" />`

Clone and simultaneously position icons on the map

`<use x="300" y="110" xlink:href="#bicicle" />`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 960 761">
   
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylp6r.png" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
  <defs>
    <filter id="a" width="154.5%" height="509.1%" x="-27.3%" y="-204.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
        </filter>
  <g id="bicycle">
     <ellipse cx="15" cy="37.467" fill="#999" fill-opacity=".9" filter="url(#a)" rx="11" ry="1.467"/>
      <path fill="#006893" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#006893" d="M15 0C6.448 0 0 6.759 0 15.726c0 11.28 13.944 21.44 14.537 21.867.138.1.302.149.463.149a.784.784 0 0 0 .463-.15C16.055 37.167 30 27.007 30 15.727 30 6.76 23.552 0 15 0z"/>
    
      <path transform="translate(2.5 2)" fill="#fff" d="M5.5,6.137a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H6.909a.249.249,0,0,1,.231.156l.637,1.568a.251.251,0,0,1-.036.25l-.35.437a.25.25,0,0,1-.3.07A4.894,4.894,0,0,0,5,10.137a5,5,0,1,0,4.856,6.19.25.25,0,0,1,.243-.19h.4a1,1,0,0,0,.807-.409l4.281-5.837a.247.247,0,0,1,.236-.1.252.252,0,0,1,.2.161l.281.762a.251.251,0,0,1-.095.293,4.978,4.978,0,1,0,2.79-.87,3.824,3.824,0,0,0-.549.046.25.25,0,0,1-.27-.161L16.92,6.6a.249.249,0,0,1,.174-.329l1.742-.435a1,1,0,0,0-.485-1.941L15.8,4.532a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.042,1.974l.08.217a.253.253,0,0,1-.008.193.25.25,0,0,1-.142.129L9.764,8.8a.251.251,0,0,1-.316-.141l-.113-.279A.178.178,0,0,1,9.5,8.137a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-.5,12a3,3,0,1,1,2.658-4.364.25.25,0,0,1-.222.364H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H7.436a.25.25,0,0,1,.222.364A2.985,2.985,0,0,1,5,18.137Zm5.049-4.076a.1.1,0,0,1-.174-.036,4.941,4.941,0,0,0-.927-1.916.249.249,0,0,1,0-.309l.609-.761a.252.252,0,0,1,.111-.08L12.5,9.95a.25.25,0,0,1,.286.383ZM19,18.137a3,3,0,0,1-3-3,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,.8-2.022.249.249,0,0,1,.417.084l.842,2.284a1,1,0,1,0,1.876-.692l-.964-2.617a.028.028,0,0,1,0-.025A.028.028,0,0,1,19,12.137a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z"/>
    
  </g>
  </defs>  
     <use x="300" y="110" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
   <use x="650" y="200" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
    <use x="650" y="450" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
   <use x="150" y="250" xlink:href="#bicycle" />   
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

When cloning icons, they can be styled.

To do this, delete the attribute `fill ="#006893"` at the parent and paint the children in different colors

`<use x="300" y="110" fill="red" xlink:href="#bicycle" />`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 960 761">
   
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylp6r.png" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
  <defs>
    <filter id="a" width="154.5%" height="509.1%" x="-27.3%" y="-204.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
        </filter>
  <g id="bicycle">
     <ellipse cx="15" cy="37.467" fill="#999" fill-opacity=".9" filter="url(#a)" rx="11" ry="1.467"/>
      <path  fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#006893" d="M15 0C6.448 0 0 6.759 0 15.726c0 11.28 13.944 21.44 14.537 21.867.138.1.302.149.463.149a.784.784 0 0 0 .463-.15C16.055 37.167 30 27.007 30 15.727 30 6.76 23.552 0 15 0z"/>
    
      <path transform="translate(2.5 2)" fill="#fff" d="M5.5,6.137a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H6.909a.249.249,0,0,1,.231.156l.637,1.568a.251.251,0,0,1-.036.25l-.35.437a.25.25,0,0,1-.3.07A4.894,4.894,0,0,0,5,10.137a5,5,0,1,0,4.856,6.19.25.25,0,0,1,.243-.19h.4a1,1,0,0,0,.807-.409l4.281-5.837a.247.247,0,0,1,.236-.1.252.252,0,0,1,.2.161l.281.762a.251.251,0,0,1-.095.293,4.978,4.978,0,1,0,2.79-.87,3.824,3.824,0,0,0-.549.046.25.25,0,0,1-.27-.161L16.92,6.6a.249.249,0,0,1,.174-.329l1.742-.435a1,1,0,0,0-.485-1.941L15.8,4.532a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.042,1.974l.08.217a.253.253,0,0,1-.008.193.25.25,0,0,1-.142.129L9.764,8.8a.251.251,0,0,1-.316-.141l-.113-.279A.178.178,0,0,1,9.5,8.137a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-.5,12a3,3,0,1,1,2.658-4.364.25.25,0,0,1-.222.364H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H7.436a.25.25,0,0,1,.222.364A2.985,2.985,0,0,1,5,18.137Zm5.049-4.076a.1.1,0,0,1-.174-.036,4.941,4.941,0,0,0-.927-1.916.249.249,0,0,1,0-.309l.609-.761a.252.252,0,0,1,.111-.08L12.5,9.95a.25.25,0,0,1,.286.383ZM19,18.137a3,3,0,0,1-3-3,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,.8-2.022.249.249,0,0,1,.417.084l.842,2.284a1,1,0,1,0,1.876-.692l-.964-2.617a.028.028,0,0,1,0-.025A.028.028,0,0,1,19,12.137a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z"/>
    
  </g>
  </defs>  
     <use x="300" y="110" fill="red" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
   <use x="650" y="200" fill="dodgerblue" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
    <use x="650" y="450" fill="purple" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
   <use x="150" y="250" fill="green" xlink:href="#bicycle" />   
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get why "the combined icon can only be used once" ? Once I save the combined file as an SVG does it matter if it contains multiple nested SVGs?

Comment: @3zzy You are right, but only if for each copy of the same icons to use copies of the same files, this is irrational.  I suggested a method when in the same svg file you can clone and position as many identical icons as you want. I do not insist on my decision The choice is yours

Comment: @Alexandr_TT your suggestion to use  `transform ="translate (2.5 2)"` works only for one icon, doesn't it? I mean, if we try to render other icon with these values then the icon won't be centered since it has different dimensions